# How do input stream and output stream of the same socket see each other?

Tags: java, sockets, stream

Hello i am studying an example of a server-client application and I do not understand how the client receives the string from the server.

The server runs a thread that does this:

```
String seq = generateSequence(l); //random stuff
        outSocket.println(seq);
```

in the client class there is this code:

```
 String serverSeq = inSocket.readLine();
        System.out.println(serverSeq);
```

and `inSocket` and `outSocket` are implemented in the same way both in the thread and in the client classes, with:

```
inSocket = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
outSocket = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
```

where `socket` is the same object too, it's the client's socket

My question is why `serverSeq` string is exactly the`seq` string? The server writes in the output stream, and the client picks up from the input stream, aren't those two different memory areas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The sockets are not the same objects. They're two instances of the same class. One runs in the server JVM, the other one in the client JVM. And the whole point of sockets is to communicate between processes over the network: the client connects to the server, and then the two sockets are connected to each other, and allow sending/receiving date. You should read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: Well the rest is context but the main question is why server is using the output stream, the client the input stream, and it sees the correct string. Shouldn't the server write on the client's input stream for it to read?

Comment: You can't write to an InputStream. An InputStream is something you read from. The client is at one end of the communication channel, and read bytes from an input stream. The server is at the other hand, on another machine, and writes to an output stream. The client reads what the server writes, and vice versa. What the server writes goes is sent over the network, and is received by the client. You seem to completely miss the fact that sockets are used to communicate over the network.

Comment: Okay; thanks for your time, this is all executed on the same computer so maybe thats what bugs me. Then how data passes from the server's output stream to the client's input stream is something low-level i do not need to know?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem actually was that I thought server's `accept()` function returned THE client's socket, but it doesn't, it returns a new socket that dialogues with the client's socket but they are two different objects, so `inSocket` and `outSocket` both in the client and in the server refer to two different sockets not the same one.

The server writes the string on its output stream and then it goes into the client's input stream which is quite logic, I was understanding that server was writing the string in the client's output stream and that didn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of underlying software, and potentially hardware at play here if you are using sockets over network.

The implementation may be dependent on OS/platform, but in general a port will be open on both ends of the pc. Data will flow between the ports in some manner, likely through some sort of memory mapped I/O and then out to network or in local case perhaps just routed by cpu or memory commands. For local case, it's likely the data gets copied into the server socket's buffer/memory space, and the readline simply reads it and repositions the address pointer to indicate that data was read.

It's all hidden to you, so unless you work on the low level code for it, you don't need to care too much about how data is sent and received, but at minimum you should understand the different protocols commonly used(TCP, UDP, RAW).

EDIT: even if you use localhost, it's likely to go out to network controller of your system and then just loopback. It's unlikely system optimizes it to bypass network controller and just copies direct to the receiving socket.